# Need to build a single soql query for related list

Tags: soql

I have an object `Project__c` where I have related list as `Phase__c` and `Toll__c`. `Project__c` is a lookup to `Phase__c` and `Toll__c`.Can i have a single soql query where i can have all the `phase__c` and `toll__c` under each project.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below query,

```
List<Project__c> lstProject=[Select id,(select id from Phases__r),(select id from Tolls__r) from Project__c];
```

> Note - Phases & Tolls are the child relationship names. You need to
>   update them if you have given some different child relationship names.

Comment: @Sid did it work?